# Email artifacts uploaded to Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, jenkins-groovy, email-ext, jenkins-email-ext

In the following step from a Jenkins job, I am uploading artifacts to Artifactory.

```
stage('Archive Artifacts'){
    steps{

        rtBuildInfo (captureEnv: true)

       rtUpload (
        serverId: 'Artifactory-1',
        spec: '''{
            "files": [
            {
                "pattern": "app/build/outputs/apk/**/*.apk",
                "target": "Spa/Dev/"
            }]
        }''')
        rtPublishBuildInfo (serverId: 'Artifactory-1')
    }
}
```

In Post events, I'm sending an email always using email-ext plugin:

```
always 
{
    emailext attachLog: true, mimeType: 'text/html', 
        body:  '''${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html.template"}''',
        to: "foo@bar.com", 
        subject: "Deploy ${env.JOB_NAME} #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}: ${currentBuild.currentResult}"
}
```

I'm using this template from here, which is ok for me:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/groovy-html.template

The Artifacts section from that template:

```
<!-- ARTIFACTS -->
<% 
def artifacts = build.artifacts
if ( artifacts != null && artifacts.size() > 0 ) { %>
<table class="section">
 <tr class="tr-title">
  <td class="td-title">BUILD ARTIFACTS</td>
</tr>
<% artifacts.each() {
  f -> %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="${rooturl}${build.url}artifact/${f}">${f}</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
<br/>
 <% } %>
```

But seems that build.artifacts is only populated if archived though 'archiveArtifacts':

```
archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: 'app/build/outputs/apk/**/*.apk', fingerprint: true, onlyIfSuccessful: true, caseSensitive: false
```

But, I want to publish in the sent email the list of archived artifacts to Artifactory.

Is it possible?
I haven't been able to find any reference for Groovy -> Jenkins -> Artifactory, in order to know what objects or properties are available in the script.

Comment: In the archive artifact stage, why don't you actually archive it as well ? Then it should work

Comment: @ThothadriRajesh That's exactly what I want to avoid. Archive in Artifactory, not in Jenkins. Jenkins should only automate the entire process. But artifacts should be somewhere outside of Jenkins scope. That's where Artifactory comes into scene: act as a artifacts repository.

Comment: found a solution for this yet?